# RestEasy @EJB returning null

Tags: jakarta-ee, resteasy, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I have a jax-rs service implemented with RestEasy, I am using Jboss as7 and have implemented a signleton ejb with the @Signleton annotation. The signleton is started when the server starts (@startup) and I would like to inject it into the jax-rs usign the @EJB. The problem is that the class is always null and I am started to get lost because in every tutorial I have looked this is the way they are injecting the ejb.
Should I use any special xml file? what am I doing wrong?

```
@Path("/")
public class Service extends Application{
@EJB
private GlobalStore store;
public Service(){
fromejbstore = store.getSentiment();//null pointer is thrown
}
}
```

the Signleton ejb is:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class GlobalStore {
 Sentiment sentiment;
 @PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
 //do something
}
public Sentiment getSentiment(){return sentiment;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem when I call from Rest services to EJB. I got null when i inject the @EJB.When I tried to add @Stateless in the services class then there is no problem. I think you can add @Stateless in your Service class. Then it will no problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have changed my code to look like this and avoid the injection:

```
    `try{
        InitialContext ctx=new InitialContext();
        localRef = (myEjb) ctx.lookup("java:global/appName/EjbName");
       }catch(NamingException ne){
            System.out.println("\n[MyRestService]NamingException: "+ne);
            ne.printStackTrace();
       }`
```

Could not find the reason the @EJB annotation is not working, probably this has something to do with the RestEasy.

Comment: I had success with : localRef = (myEjb) ctx.lookup("java:global/app-ear/app-ejb/EjbName!br.com.somestuff.ejbinterfacename");

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the @EJB annotation injection doesn't work for POJOs - try turning your Service class into a stateless session bean (by adding @Stateless annotation on the class level) and the GlobalStore injection should work like a charm

Comment: This should be a comment to the OP question as it does not atempt to answer it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are activating your JAX-RS the wrong way. A class extending `Application` and annotated with `@ApplicationPath` is the Java EE 6 "no XML" approach to activate JAX-RS.

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
 /* class body intentionally left blank */
}
```

Then your `Service` should be in the same package like `JaxRsActivator` but does not need to extend `Application`:

```
@Path("/test")
public class Service
{
  @EJB private GlobalStore store;

  @GET @Path("/test")
  public String getTime()
  {
   boolean test = (store==null);
   return "Test: "+test;
  }
}
```

You can test it with your browser `http://<host>/<context>/rest/test/test`.

Comment: Even though this is not a good way to create your service it is not forbidden and actually works. This is not my problem the service is working the ejb reference is null

Comment: At least this is way proposed in the `org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-ear-webapp-archetype` archetype. Then your problem is located elsewhere, with the annotations `@Singleton`, `@Startup` and `@EJB` my reference is not `null`.

Comment: When on debug the ejb is started I think this has to do something with packaging or resteasy not being able to find the correct context.

Comment: You can try to lookup your EJB in a @SessionBean to verify it's available for other components.

Comment: I have create another project (dynamic web project with CDI this time) to test the same ejb using the same server and the same annotations... The ejb is injected as expected. I think this is a problem with the RestEasy ( browsing the net I have found this: https://community.jboss.org/thread/170194)

Answer (score 0):

The supplied answer above is correct. Add @Stateless to the service, add a @Local annotated interface which the service implements, then in the class access that stateless bean by adding @EJB to a reference of that interface. The only other thing you might have to do which I had to on Websphere Liberty Profile was create the beans.xml file in WEB-INF directory to stop the NPE on that cdi bean.

```
@Stateless
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I did something");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("I was just constructed");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        System.out.println("Arrgg I am being destroyed");
    }
}

@Local
public interface Service {
    public void doSomething();
}


public class Client {

    @EBJ Service service;

    public void someMethod() {
        service.doSomething();
    }
}
```

../WEB-INF/beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

You can add the post construct and pre destroy annotated methods on your bean to see it being created and destroyed when the app boots up and shuts down.

Answer (score -2):

add beans.xml in web-inf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

and change the class extends Application:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")

public class YourApplication extends Application
{
   HashSet<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

   public YourApplication()
   {
      getClasses().add(yourOwnClass.class);
   }

   @Override
   public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
   {
      HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
      return set;
   }

    enter code here

   @Override
   public Set<Object> getSingletons()
   {
      return singletons;  
   }
}
```